# How to make code interpret $ but not *?

Tags: shell-script, perl, escape-characters

I have some perl code (don't focus on what it does right now, i'm still working on it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

if(!@ARGV)
{
  print ("ERROR: NO ARGS\n");
  exit 1;
}

else
{
  use Cwd qw(cwd);
  my $dir = cwd;

  print $ARGV[0];
  @allfiles = glob($ARGV[0]);

  foreach $file (@allfiles){
    print "$file\n";
  }
}
```

On the line `@allfiles = glob($ARGV[0]);` the contents of ARGV[0] are being interpreted.  I don't want them to be.  For example, if ARGV[0] is *.txt, it will just interpret the metacharacter.  I don't want it to do that.  I want it to use "*.txt" as the input for glob();  How do I do this?

Comment: How are you running the command? What is your argument list?

Comment: If you do **not** want `$ARGV[0]` to be interpreted as a glob pattern, then why are you passing it to `glob`? write simply `@allfiles = $ARGV[0]`.

Comment: Show how you call this Perl script from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one case where I suggest using bash aliases rather than functions. The bash manual says `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions`, this is the exception.

Normally if you say

```
 perl script *.txt
```

then the shell will expand the *.txt. This can be turned off using 'set +f'. The problem with using a function is that by the time the function is invoked, the shell has already expanded the pattern, so the trick is to use a combination of an alias and a function.

```
alias script="set +f ; _script"
_script(){ set -f ; perl script "$@" ; }
```

Then running

```
 script *.txt
```

will be processed as "set +f ; _script *.txt", so the pattern expansion is turned off before the _script function is invoked. The function turns pattern expansion back on, and then invokes the perl script.

The other way to avoid the issue is to use shell quoting, and say

```
  perl script '*.txt'
```

and the quotes will prevent the shell from doing the pattern expansion.

Comment: That is a fascinating hack.

Answer (score 1):

With the `zsh` shell, you can use:

```
alias myscript='noglob myscript'
```

`noglob` is a shell keyword that prevents globbing in the arguments (not redirections if `multios` is on) of the following simple command.

Note that you can still do

```
ENV_VAR=value myscript args
```

or

```
<input myscript args
```

Or you can simply use

```
myscript "*.$ext"
```

If you want the `$ext` to be expanded, but not the glob.